# How can I get the size of index of a table?

Tags: python, pytables

In pytables, for table size I can use `size_on_disk` and `size_in_memory`.

```
h5f.get_node('/df00/table').size_on_disk
Out[51]: 73514971
h5f.get_node('/df00/table').size_in_memory
Out[52]: 437860080
```

But I also want to check the size of index if there is any, since using different indexing parameter results in different index size. The index also has its own compressor filter.

```
h5f.get_node('/df00/table').colindexes
Out[53]: 
{
    "index": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
    "level_1": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
    "level_0": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False}
```

I would like to check both compressed index size and uncompressed index size.
Can any one share this knowledge? Thanks!